# Mercurial OS X extension enabling

Tags: macos, mercurial

I'm a new mac user and recently installed mercurial on it. Id like to enable a few extensions and am looking for the global hgrc file.

I could'nt find it, so i tried creating "hgrc" files in /etc/mercurial, and ~/.hg .

It still does not work, so I was wondering if someone here had the solved the problem.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `.hgrc` needs to be at `~/.hgrc`, just like on other unix-like OSes (assuming you're using the standard Mercurial installation and not something like MacHg).  You can use `/etc/mercurial`, but in that case the file is named `hgrc`, and not `.hgrc`.

You can also ask `hg` this question directly, and it should give you the most up-to-date answer for your installation:

```
$ hg help config
Configuration Files

    Mercurial reads configuration data from several files, if they exist. Below we list the most specific file first.

    On Unix, these files are read:

    - "<repo>/.hg/hgrc"
    - "$HOME/.hgrc"
    - "/etc/mercurial/hgrc"
    - "/etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/*.rc"
    - "<install-root>/etc/mercurial/hgrc"
    - "<install-root>/etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/*.rc"
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe Mercurial looks for `~/.hgrc`. Try there.

https://blogs.oracle.com/edwingo/entry/using_mercurial_on_mac_os